# How to integrate two scales for single Y-axis

Tags: anychart

anychart.theme(anychart.themes.darkEarth);

anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {

```
var dataSet = anychart.data.set([
    ['P1', 969.5, 2040, 1200, 1600,2000],
    ['P2', 779.1, 1794, 1124, 1724,4000],
    ['P3', 739.2, 2026, 1006, 1806,5000]
]);


var seriesData_1 = dataSet.mapAs({x: [0], value: [1]});


var seriesData_2 = dataSet.mapAs({x: [0], value: [2]});


var seriesData_3 = dataSet.mapAs({x: [0], value: [3]});


var seriesData_4 = dataSet.mapAs({x: [0], value: [4]});

 var seriesData_5 = dataSet.mapAs({x: [0], value: [5]});


chart = anychart.column();


chart.animation(true);


chart.container('container');


chart.title('Combination of Stacked Column and Line Chart (Dual Y-Axis)');

var scale = anychart.scales.linear();

scale.stackMode('value');


chart.column(seriesData_2);


var lineSeries = chart.area(seriesData_1);
lineSeries.yScale(scale);



var lineSeries2 = chart.area(seriesData_5);
lineSeries2.yScale(scale);


chart.column(seriesData_3);


chart.column(seriesData_4);


chart.draw();
```

});

I am trying to add a Series Column chart with Stacked Area.
But the Series Column and Stacked Area should have different Scales to make them separate from Stacking.
How to integrate these two Scales into the Yaxis.
Is there any to do that? Please do suggest!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use additional axis from the left or from the right of the chart.

Left axis example:

```
var secondYAxis = chart.yAxis(1).scale(scale);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cgquc1pz/1/

Right axis example:

```
var secondYAxis = chart.yAxis(1).scale(scale);
secondYAxis.orientation('right');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cgquc1pz/2/